Printing Popup Hangs over 5 seconds for each page
Our problem is while printing after the calculations, windows printing popup hangs over 5 seconds then it prints for each page. But this issue does not always happen, once it starts to happen we never figured out a solution so we always ask our customers to format their pc. On a slow printing computer, if we move our program from C:\Program Files\OurAppsDirectory\exe to somewhere like C:\Users\user\some path\exe problem goes away and it prints normally.
Things that tried and did not work

Not sending default, selecting printer in code
Giving Users permission to our app folder
Instead of dotnet net framework System.Printing using nuget package System.Printing.Common

We think this is caused by faulty Windows Update but don't know which one. In customers event viewers, we see a lot of Errors some are Windows Update some not, around the days customers start having printing problem.
We use regular PrintDocument to print, also do not print images either. Just regular sentences with default Segoe UI font, calculate font sizes and rectangles etc. Nothing fancy.
var document = new PrintDocument();
document.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "printer name";
document.PrintPage += printDocument1_PrintPage;
document.Print();

const int PRINT_PAGE_WITDH = 240;
const int PRINT_PAGE_HEIGHT = 160;
Font font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
SolidBrush _brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    string text = "Hello, World";
    var textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, font);
    var x = (PRINT_PAGE_WITDH - textSize.Width) / 2;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, font, _brush, x, 77);
}


There's not really enough information here to help you work out what your problem is. If it's your code, you could profile it to work out what's going on. Have you considered though that it might be something like an antivirus scanner? The fact it doesn't happen when you move it to a user folder is suspicious.

You haven't provided any code, so no one can see if your code has an issue, nor have you provided any error messages from Event Viewer. You listed some things that you tried, but one thing that you didn't mention-which should be one of the first things to try-is to reboot the computer. Have you tried rebooting the computer when the issue occurs?

@Lunivore I will try printing with defender off and also will exclude it from scanning to confirm whether it is defender problem. I've added mininal example code.

@Itallmakescents I'll gather error logs from customer by tomorrow(around ~12-18 hours) and share them.
